# string indices must be integers error in python, but indices are integers

Tags: python, string, indices

I'm writing a program to add two numbers from a single line of input of the form:

number + othernumber

I keep getting a "string indices must be integers" error, but when I call type on all the indices, they all show up as integers.

How do I fix this?
Here's the code

```
S = input()
for position in range(0, len(S)):
   if '+'== position:
     break
a=int(position)
Sum = (S[0,a])+(S[a, len(S)])
print(Sum)
#print(position)   
#print(type(position))
#print(type(len(S)))
#print(type(0))
```

Comment: When you post on SO, please include the error as it comes from Python - there is more information available there that you have not given us.

Comment: Also note your code doesn't make sense - `'+' == position` will never evaluated to `True` as `position` is a number. Note that what you are trying to do here is better achieved with one of the many [methods on strings](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: but the '+' == position thing seems to work, when I run print(position), it gives back the position of the '+' sign

Comment: The only time I can imagine it working is if `'+'` is the last character in the string, as when the loop ends, `position` will always be set to the last value in the range. Take a look at your code and it's clear that it doesn't make sense. You are looping through a range of numbers and comparing them to a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The immediate issue

You probably meant to use `S[0:a]` and `S[a:len(S)]` (slicing) rather than commas.

### A note about slicing...

You don't have to specify the leading zero or the trailing `len(S)` there - they're implicit. So you could just use `S[:a]` and `S[a:]` to mean the same thing.

Also note that `S[0:a] + S[a:len(S)]` is equivalent to `S`. You probably didn't want to include the `+` in there, so you'd probably want to use `S[a+1:len(S)]` instead.

### Another note about finding the position of a character in a string

You don't need to loop over the indices manually - there's already the `.index()` method of strings to do this:

```
>>> "hello".index("e")
1
```

## A simpler way to accomplish your overall goal

You can just use the `split()` function to get the parts of a string separated by the `+` character:

```
S = input()
number_strings = S.split('+')
numbers = [int(n) for n in number_strings]
print sum(numbers)
```

As a bonus, this will work for an arbitrary number of numbers - `1+2+3` would work, as would just `4`.

The third line uses what's called a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to operate on each of the elements of a list and generate a new one - in this case, taking a list of strings and making a list of integers.

The fourth line takes advantage of Python's build in `sum()` function, which will automatically return the sum of a sequence of items.

Note that you could also condense the above lines:

```
print sum(int(n) for n in input().split('+'))
```

This is a much tidier form; I just spaced it out above to make it easier to explain.

Comment: +1, a good answer that gives a lot of important extra information. Note that you might want to explain the the [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: Awesome, I'd +1 again if I could.

Answer (score 0):

`0, a` is a tuple. Did you mean to **slice** the sequence instead, via `S[0:a]`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify the , to :

```
Sum = (S[0:a])+(S[a: len(S)])
```

Comment: This won't add the numbers, it will concatenate the strings.